# Updating tableview from a second view controller

Tags: swift, tableview

I have a class called `Deck` which has a property as an array of a struct called cards. I have a tableview set to display each deck by name. I also have a view controller to enter a name used to either add a new deck or save over an old deck. It works fine when adding a new deck, however whenever I update an old deck, instead of simply updating the name, it creates an exact copy and adds it to the table view.

Here is my prepare for a segue from the `DeckEditViewController`:

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
    //configure the destination view controller only when the save button is pressed.
    guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem, button == saveButton else {
        print("The save button was not pressed, canceling")
        return
    }

    let name = deckNameTextField.text ?? ""
    let cards = deck?.cards

    deck = Deck(name: name, cards: cards ?? [])
}
```

And here is my unwind in my table view controller:

```swift
@IBAction func unwindToDeckList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? DeckEditViewController, let deck = sourceViewController.deck {

        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            //Update existing deck
            decks[selectedIndexPath.row] = deck
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
            print("Updating existing deck")
        }
        else {
            //add new deck
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: decks.count, section: 0)

            decks.append(deck)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
            print("Adding a new deck")
        }
    }
}
```

If anybody can help at least point me in the right direction, I am lost. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use delegates for pass data to other view and then reload the tableview, I understand this: you have a table view, you pass to other view, in the second view you update the data, you back to first view and you want to update the data, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Currently, I have got it to pass the data into the second view where I can change the name. However, when I hit save, my table view should be updating the cell that was sent to that second view. Instead when the data is being sent back to the table view, it is adding another row instead of updating the existing cell.

Comment: The data being passed back is a Class with a property of an array of items. I am wondering if this has something to do with how I am passing that array back?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom protocol - delegate as per your requirements or you can use Notification Center for pass data. 
If you are new to learn things then check these sites to know more about Delegates.

1. [Delegation-Pattern](https://medium.com/@nimjea/delegation-pattern-in-swift-4-2-f6aca61f4bf5)
2. [Understanding Delegates and Delegation](https://www.appcoda.com/swift-delegate/)
3. [Implementing delegates](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef)

You can check, How to pass data using delegate on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ekQ0pqzc9Kg) also.
I hope this may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use closures. Define a closure in the second view controller.

```
var somethingHappened: (() -> Void)?
```

Implement it in the first view controller.

```
secondVC.somethingHappened = { [weak self] in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Those are just simple examples of usage. You can send data using closures as well.

```
var somethingHappened: ((String) -> Void)?

secondVC.somethingHappened = { [weak self] (something) in
    // use the coming data
}
```

Using closures you don't need to write protocols. So you gain in coding time.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong. I was accessing the second view controller through a cell accessory which apparently does not automatically pass an index value. Once I manually passed that value I was able to properly update the old data.